# Additional authentication via script's exit status upon OpenVPN client connection to the server

Tags: scripts, vpn, openvpn

I'm currently using the pam plugin to authenticate openvpn clients. It is working fine. I'm using duplicate certificates but need to do subsequent checks on the host - a home-brew Pulse Secure hostchecker.

I've tried client-connect, up, etc but it's not working. I might be going about it all wrong. Both client-connect and up give me:

> WARNING: Failed running command (): external program exited with error status: 1

The script I want to send to the client looks for the existence of a 'secret' file. The real world implementation will look for 10 files but I wanted to keep it simple. In conclusion, I need to authenticate *AND* look for this file in order to allow a connection. Ideally the client gets a message like "Not an approved platform.". Is this possible when I can't have users modify their ovpn file?

#### `hostcheck.sh` (777 permissions)

```bsh
cat hostcheck.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /etc/secretfile ] ; then 
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi

exit 1
```

#### `server.conf`

```
duplicate-cn
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
#auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/hostcheck.sh via-file
script-security 2 
#client-connect /etc/openvpn/hostcheck.sh
up /etc/openvpn/hostcheck.sh
username-as-common-name
#tmp-dir /dev/shm
tmp-dir /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tried running the script from the command line?  Does it return `exit 1`? Have you tried debugging your `if` statement? Does `/etc/secretfile` exist? If it doesn't, the script is doing what you're asking it to do. What are the permissions for the `secretfile`? If the user can't access it, then it may not "exist" to them.

### Lock a user account via expiry

Instead of putting the file there, or removing it, could you just lock the account?

Lock the account when you don't want the user to access the machine:

```
usermod username -e 1999-01-01
```

When you want to allow access, unlock the account:

```
usermod username -e
```

Here, we use something native to Linux authentication (vs our own, custom scripts) to solve the problem, which should help prevent additional security risks.  You could shiv this in as you described if you really wanted or needed to do so.  For example, lock/unlock the account, using a `cron` job, or by polling for the files, vs complicating auth upon connection.

---

### Restrict via blacklist/whitelist groups in `pam`

If you don't want users accessing the entire system, vs restricting individual users, you have other options, such as disabling SSH entirely, limiting SSH connection to a whitelist CIDR block, or most simply and in-line with your goals, using `pam` against a specific group.

#### `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`

```
auth required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/login.group.allowed
```

#### `/etc/login.group.allowed`

```
wheel
sudo
```

In this example, we only allow users in `wheel` or `sudo` to login.  This will allow you to disable login to most users, while letting some admins access, or revoke all access if you so choose.  You'll want to make sure this is owned by `root` and has something like `644` permissions to prevent unauthorized writes (modeled after `/etc/password` permissions).

---

### Use two-factor, one-time passwords (OTP) in `pam`

This is just a cool, alternative that could help restrict access based on a list of users with access to OTP secrets. The [`pam_oath`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_oath) module is easy to set up, and supports FOSS clients, such as [Authenticator](https://github.com/0xbb/otp-authenticator).  This example shows user-based OTP, but can be adjusted for groups, similar to the previous example.  You'll need `oath-toolkit` and want `qrencode`.

```bsh
touch /etc/users.oath
chown 600 /etc/users.oath # Will contain sensitive information
vim /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

```
#%PAM-1.0
#auth     required  pam_securetty.so     #disable remote root
#auth      include   system-remote-login
auth      required  pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=30 digits=6
account   include   system-remote-login
password  include   system-remote-login
session   include   system-remote-login
```

With each user:

```bsh
USER=myusername
SECRET=$(head -10 /dev/urandom | sha512sum | cut -b 1-30)
echo "HOTP/T30/6 ${USER} - ${SECRET}" >> /etc/users.oauth
QR_SECRET=$(oauthtool -v -d6 ${SECRET} | grep "Base32 secret" | awk '{print $3}')
qrencode -o ${USER}-OTP-secret.png $QR_SECRET
```

This will only allow key-based authentication, followed by the requirement of entering the one-time password at login.  There are command line OTP generators, but typically QR codes are used bring in the credentials.  The SECRET and QR_SECRET and resulting image file should all be treated as confidential and ultimately be deleted after  setting up the OTP client.